# How to fetch Date and time in JavaScript for a given timezone with daylight saving

Tags: javascript, datetime

How to fetch Date and time in JavaScript for a given time zone with daylight saving

Below is the function that I have used but there are other parameters to find if  DST is enabled

- (UTC-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada)
- (UTC-07:00) Chihuahua, La
- Paz, Mazatlan (UTC-07:00) Arizona

here Arizona doesn't fall under DST, whereas other 2 Timezones have DST,
So how to fetch date and time for MST with DST?

```
var $DateUTC = new Date();
ConvertDateTimeFormat($DateUTC ,-7)

function ConvertDateTimeFormat($InputDate,$TimeZone)
{

        var $DateUTC = new Date();
        var $utc = $DateUTC.getTime() + ($DateUTC.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
        var $Current_Date_BasedOn_TimeZone = new Date($utc + (3600000*-$TimeZone));
        var $Date = $Current_Date_BasedOn_TimeZone.toISOString();
        _log("The Current Time for given time zone"+$TimeFormat+" Is" +$Date);
}
```

Comment: have you tried to use `http://momentjs.com/`? This is quite convenient.

Comment: So you have city names and a date as input and you want to convert it to UTC?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  Have you researched this problem?  The code you showed is flawed in several ways: 1) time zone != offset (see the `timezone` tag wiki`), 2) you are shifting the time around with addition/subtraction - that picks a *different* moment in time - it does *not* adjust the time zone.  Lots of material on StackOverflow about this already...